# How to edit the product view in front end magento?

Tags: magento, view, product

I want to add the some links at the product view time and display it in the front end.

For example product shirt and I want to add two link at the product view time Link Name Like Style Fabric and within these link I want to change image according to select size and fabric.

Comment: What have you tried that is not working? This is a Q&A site, what is your exact question? Stating that you don't know how to do something and begging for help is not a substitute for a concrete question, providing code that you think should work, but doesn't. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 1.9, this can be achieved with the help of configurable swatches.

Following in-depth tutorials will help you:

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch-setup.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog|Swatches|Swatch%2520Configuration|_____0

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#catalog/product-configurable-swatch.html%3FTocPath%3DProduct%2520Catalog|Swatches|_____0